# Abrir uma aba, passando dados trazidos do result do firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Caros, estou testando como funciona a autenticação do firebase, eu consigo autenticar de todas formas(Github, FB, Twitter, Google) mas so consigo usar o dados do result, na pagina inicial. 
Gostaria de saber como eu poderia abrir uma outra aba e conseguir usar os dados do retorno do firebase, porque os dados do meu result fica disponível apenas na pagina inicial. Ate tento abrir uma aba usando window.location.href mas não sei se e possível passar os dados do result.

**HTML pagina inicial(índex.html)**

```
 <button  id="authGitHubButton">
       Log in with GitHub
 </button>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Autenticar com GitHub

var authGitHubButton = document.getElementById('authGitHubButton');

    authGitHubButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Providers
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
        window.location.href = "/access.html";
        signIn(provider);
    });

function signIn(provider) {
    firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            displayName.innerText = 'Ola, ' + result.user.displayName;
            photoURL.setAttribute("src", result.user.photoURL);
            photoURL.style.display = 'block';
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Falha na autenticação');
        });
}
```

**HTML nova aba(access.html)**

```
   <h3 id="displayName"></h3>
   <img class="photoURL text-center image-responsive" id="photoURL" src=""></img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você está utilizando a abordagem de callbacks pra receber os dados, mas ao usar o Firebase algumas vezes utilizamos eventos para processar estas informações.

Ao utilizar:

```
firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(function (result) { ...
```

Os dados resultantes só serão computados naquele momento, mas a API do Firebase lhe fornece um token de acesso à plataforma desejada para ter acesso direto à API do provider de autenticação, conforme a [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?authuser=0):

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // Isto te dá um token de acesso ao Google. Você pode utilizar ele para accessar a Google API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // A informação do usuário logado.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    // ...
    });
```

Mas no caso da autenticação do Firebase e dos dados do usuário você pode registrar uma função que será executada assim que o Firebase realizar login/logoff, repassando dados do usuário, esse evento também é disparado quando a página é recarregada e o login ainda está ativo (o token ainda é válido) e será executada quando o Firebase carregar e detectar e validar o token, conforme [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start?authuser=0):

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
        var uid = user.uid;
        var providerData = user.providerData;
        // ...
    } else {
        // User is signed out.
        // ...
    }
    });
```

Esse método é executado não interessando qual o método de autenticação utilizado.

Comment: Romulo tentei de usar estas informações, mas não tive sucesso. Poderias mostrar como ficaria meu código, baseado na informação que você passou, porque das formas que tentei, não deu certo.

Comment: [Exemplo](https://github.com/Yemolai/firebase-github-auth-example/blob/master/public/index.html) no GitHub pra você clonar e rodar, onde alterei a abordagem para o uso do evento AuthStateChanged. (Precisa colocar seus dados de firebase no `public/javascripts/firebase.js`)

Comment: thanks Rômulo!!